# CodeIgniter http://127.0.0.1 page not found problem

Tags: php, codeigniter

I’ve recently started with `Codeignigter` on local windows machine.

I have install the IIS and extracted only ci folder and place `index.php`, application, system and `user_guide`  in `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot`.

I've made change in the `application/config/config.php`  to  `$config['base_url'] = "http://127.0.0.1/";`

now i am trying to excess   http://127.0.0.1 and http://127.0.0.1/index.php but it shows page not found.

Can anyone tell me how can i fix this Or what else i have to install

Comment: Look at the IIS logs for errors you need to resolve.

Comment: Are you sure that IIS' web root is set to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot? Can you access the User Guide at http://127.0.0.1/user_guide/? The problem is most like a server configuration issue.

Comment: Is the server set up correctly? is the address right (are you using another port than default one) ?

Comment: I think you need to create a folder for your project: http://127.0.0.1/your_project

Comment: Did you install PHP to IIS, and also did you set up a web.config file (iis equivalent to .htaccess) in order to properly use CI's URI routing?

Comment: Page not found?  As in, you're getting a 404 error?  Or is your browser saying it couldn't find the server?  Debug this issue with Fiddler if you aren't sure.  http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

may be you have set host name  as localhost  or root in xampp or wamp what ever server you using.just check

> phpmyadmin

to conform.